# Predicting from glmmTMB with truncated counts

Tags: r, glmmtmb

I'm running a glmmTMB model with various truncated count distributions (`truncated_poisson`, `truncated_compois`, `truncated_nbinom1`, `truncated_nbinom2`). When I predict from the model, the values seem to be lower than expected, as if the prediction is not accounting for the truncation. Where am I going wrong? A toy example is provided, showing that predicted values are lower than observed means.

Any advice would be appreciated. Extra points if the advice can extend to the other truncated count distributions (see above) and if it shows how to correctly get the 95% confidence band around the estimated values in these cases.

```
library(dplyr)
library( extraDistr)
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 20), N = rtpois(40, 1, a = 0), ran = "a") %>%
        mutate(N = ifelse(N == 0, 1, N))
m <- glmmTMB(N ~ Group + (1|ran), data = df, family = "truncated_poisson")

df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(mean(N))
predict(m, newdata = data.frame(Group = c("a", "b"), ran = NA), type = "response")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the main issue is *probably* that you're using a slightly older version of `glmmTMB` (< 1.1.5, where a bug was fixed, see e.g. e.g. https://github.com/glmmTMB/glmmTMB/issues/860).

### sample data

streamlined slightly (we don't need to include a random effect for this example), and adding a truncated nbinom2.

```r
library(dplyr)
library(extraDistr)
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 20),
                 Np = rtpois(40, 1, a = 0))

## clunky trunc nbinom generator
tnb <- rep(0, 40)
z <- (tnb==0)
while(any(z)) {
    tnb[z] <- rnbinom(sum(z), mu = 1, size = 1)
    z <- (tnb==0)
}
df$Nnb <- tnb
## summarize
df %>% group_by(Group) %>% summarize(across(starts_with("N"), mean))
##   Group    Np   Nnb
## 1 a      1.75  1.8 
## 2 b      1.45  2.35
```

### fit models

```r
m1 <- glmmTMB(Np ~ Group, data = df, family = "truncated_poisson")
m2 <- update(m1, Nnb ~ ., family = truncated_nbinom2)
```

Predicting with `se.fit = TRUE` will give you standard errors for the predictions, from which you can compute confidence intervals (assuming Normality/Wald intervals/blah blah blah ...) ...

```r
pfun <- function(m, level = 0.95) {
    pp <- predict(m, newdata = data.frame(Group = c("a", "b")),
            type = "response",
            se.fit = TRUE)
    list(est = unname(pp$fit), 
         lwr = unname(pp$fit + qnorm((1-level)/2)*pp$se.fit),
         upr = unname(pp$fit + qnorm((1+level)/2)*pp$se.fit))

}
pfun(m1)
pfun(m2)
```

Comment: Well, that was an easier fix than I expected. Thank you! Two follow-ups: 1) I thought that using the SE from response predictions wasn't proper for a glm, and that I'm supposed to  predict on the link scale and then back-transform? 2) A while back, I asked a question about the possibility of using glmmTMB without a random effect. Care to post an answer, seeing how it's apparently possible? https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/511029/can-glmmtmb-be-used-without-a-random-effect?noredirect=1#comment1105924_511029

Comment: (1) oops, yes, you're right - it would be better to predict on the link scale and back-transform (the solution above is approximately OK for *large* samples/low uncertainty ...); (2) will post.

Comment: How would I go about the back-transformation in the case of truncated distributions? This was my original intent in my question, apologies for not specifying that. Obviously I can't just exponentiate the link, since that gives me the non-truncated Poisson value...

Comment: Since there wasn't an answer to the part about predicting on the link scale, I ended up posting a new question...  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77359725/predicting-from-glmmtmb-with-truncated-counts-using-link-predictions

Answer (score 1):

Maybe to add another alternative to get the results shown in Ben's answer, you could use the *ggeffects* package to get predictions for those models. However, in order to correctly detect the zero-inflation, you have to specify `ziformula = ~1`, then `type = "zero_inflated"` will give you predictions on the response scale, taking the zero-inflation part into account.

```r
library(ggeffects)
library(extraDistr)
library(glmmTMB)

set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(Group = rep(c("a", "b"), each = 20), Np = rtpois(40, 1, a = 0))

## clunky trunc nbinom generator
tnb <- rep(0, 40)
z <- (tnb==0)
while (any(z)) {
  tnb[z] <- rnbinom(sum(z), mu = 1, size = 1)
  z <- (tnb == 0)
}
df$Nnb <- tnb

m1 <- glmmTMB(Np ~ Group, ziformula = ~1, data = df, family = "truncated_poisson")
m2 <- update(m1, Nnb ~ ., family = truncated_nbinom2)

ggpredict(m1, "Group", type = "zero_inflated")
#> # Predicted counts of Np
#> 
#> Group | Predicted |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#> a     |      1.75 | [0.77, 2.73]
#> b     |      1.45 | [0.78, 2.12]
ggpredict(m2, "Group", type = "zero_inflated")
#> # Predicted counts of Nnb
#> 
#> Group | Predicted |       95% CI
#> --------------------------------
#> a     |      1.80 | [0.83, 2.77]
#> b     |      2.35 | [0.91, 3.79]
```

<sup>Created on 2023-11-03 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>